# Error while running again php artisan session:table command in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am beginner to Laravel, when i run the command "php artisan session:table" first time it successfully created the session migration but unfortunately i have deleted this file. Now when running again this command "php artisan session:table"
its getting error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBjK1.png)

Please tell me where laravel stores that information that session migration is already created.

Regards,
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

Delete `CreateSessionsTable` migration in this folder

```
database/migrations
```

Run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then you can run

```
php artisan session:table
```

again.

Comment: KmasterYC thanks for reply

I have tried this but still getting same error.

Comment: You can check `migrations table` in your database. Then delete that migration